# Undo incorrect click in Review queue

Tags: discussion, support, review-page

So my A.D.D. was if full effect today and I clicked the *No Action Needed* button in my Review queue when I meant to click on *not an answer.*

Clicking around I could find no "undo" or way to revise what I had done, though I did eventually open open the answer and it did allow me to flag the answer as I wanted to originally.

1. Did I screw up with my second action?
2. Is there a way to undo an incorrect click in the review queue, or did I figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reviews are not changeable - if you mess up, you can always fess up. Moderators do it all the time - we chat or fix as needed when we mis click, mis read or just mistakenly think. Better to go back and fix it in my experience.

Good thinking taking action to hunt it down and flag or otherwise get the result you wish you had chosen initially.